# Convex maximization problem (existence and uniqueness)

Tags: matrices, optimization

**Short summary:**

Let $n > k \geq 2$. I am given an arbitrary full column rank $n \times k$ matrix $W$ whose rows sum up to $1$. I am trying to find a square matrix $R$ such that $W R$ has certain properties:

- component-wise, it should be  non-negative and each of its rows should sum up to $1$.
- $R$ maximizes the sum of column-wise variances of $W R$.

Does such an $R$ exist? If so, is it unique up to permutation of columns?

---

**Detailed statement of the problem:**

Let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ (where $n > k$) be a full-rank matrix which fulfills $W\mathbb{1}_k = \mathbb{1}_n$. 
Here, $\mathbb{1}_k$ is the vector of ones with length $k$.

Let $f_W: \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the sum of column-wise variances of $W R$, i.e.,

$$f_W(R) = \sum\limits_{l=1}^k \frac{1}{n-1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\left(W R\right)_{i,l} - \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \left(W R\right)_{j,l}\right)^2 $$

If I calculated correctly, the Hessian of each of the $k$ summands of $f_W$ equals $2$ times the covariance matrix of $W$, and therefore $f_W$ is convex as the sum of convex functions.

I am wondering whether the optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & f_W(R)\\ \text{subject to} & R\mathbb{1}_k = \mathbb{1}_k\\ & W R \geq 0\end{array}$$

where the inequality is component-wise, has a solution and whether this solution is unique up to permutation of columns.

I think the answer is "yes" if $k=2$, but I have not been able to say much about the general case $k > 2$.
Can anyone give me a hint on how to tackle this?

---

**Two other expressions for the objective function:**

We can also write $f_W$ as

$$f_W(R) = \frac{1}{n-1} \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{l=1}^k \left(\left(WR\right)_{i,l} - \frac{1}{k}\right)^2 - n\sum\limits_{l=1}^k \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \left(W R\right)_{j,l} - \frac{1}{k}\right)^2\right).$$

So, to maximize $f_W$, the entries of $WR$ should be as far from $\frac{1}{k}$ as possible under the constraints while its column means should be close to $\frac{1}{k}$.

Another expression for $f_W$ is

$$f_W(R) = \frac{1}{n-1} \left(\|WR\|^2 - \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{l=1}^k \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \left(WR\right)_{j,l}\right)^2\right) = \frac{1}{n-1} \left(\|WR\|^2 - \frac{1}{n} \|\mathbb{1}^\top_n WR\|^2\right),$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

Comment: I have added two expressions for $f_W$. Unfortunately, I'm not really getting anywhere from those two. From the first one, I would suspect that, ideally, the rows of $WR$ should be unit vectors which are arranged in such a way that the column sums are equal, if possible, or differ by at most 1. But I don't know if/how that could be shown.

Comment: Addendum: I don't think it is always possible to choose $R$ such that the above holds, but maybe one could choose $R$ such that $WR$ is as close as possible to its "ideal" value...

Comment: @Lithiesque I think $f_W$ is not necessarily strictly convex, because there are cases when $f_W(R)=0$ for all $R$, as you recently found out.

Comment: @supinf You are right, thank you. If I am not mistaken again, I think that $f_W$ is still convex, but not necessarily strictly convex. I have adjusted the question accordingly (and also restricted it to the case that primarily interests me, namely $k \geq 2$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a maximal $R$ does exist.

Here is a rough sketch for the existence of a maximal $R$.
A common approach to show existence of minimizers and maximizers
is to use that the feasible set is compact and the objective function is continuous.

Since $f_W(R)$ only depends on $WR$ there is a function $g$
such that $g(WR)=f_W(R)$ for all $R$.

Let us define the affine subspace $A:=\{WR \mid R\mathbb{1}_k=\mathbb{1}_k\}
\subset \mathbb R^{n\times k}$.
We consider the substitution $Z=WR$.
Then one can show that the maximization problem is equivalent to
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & g(Z)\\ \text{subject to} & 
Z\mathbb{1}_k = \mathbb{1}_n\\ & Z \geq 0
\\ &Z\in A.
\end{array} $$
Now one can show that the feasible set of this problem is compact
and that the function $g$ is continuous. Thus a maximizer $Z$ must exist.
The existence of a maximal $R$ for the original problem follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have two questions: 
1.) Shouldn't it be $A := \{WR | R\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}\}$? I think, according to your definition, $A$ is no linear subspace (not closed to scalar multiplication).
2.) Can we say anything about uniqueness of the maximum using this approach?

Comment: @Lithiesque thank you, $A$ is not a linear subspace, but an affine subspace. I was not able to find a counterexample for uniqueness. It could happen that the same $Z$ can be reached with different $R$ matrices, or the maximizer $Z$ is not unique (up to a permutation of columns).